# Minimum in array in javascript ignoring particular element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of 3 elements.

```
var arr = [-1,2,-1];
```

how to find minimum in this array, when i want to ignore the '-1' in the array irrespective of it's position i.e.

```
var arr = [-1,1,3];     //should give 1
var arr = [-1,2,-1];    //should give 2
var arr = [1,0,-1,4,5,2];    //should give 0
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a homework coding service.

Comment: What have you tried so far to accomplish this task? How can you extend a standard `min` function to ignore any negative numbers?

Comment: @olaf sorry to say!! but this is not homework. Actually requiere this code for UIpath so can't use JS functions like min, max

Comment: I am not a good coder, i know that's why seeking help

Comment: `Math.min.apply(null, arr.filter(x => x >= 0))`

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the values and take the minimum out of it.

```js
var array = [1, 0, -1, 4, 5, 2],
    min = Math.min(...array.filter(a => a !== -1));
    
console.log(min);
```

Comment: Thanx @Nina Scholz

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#reduce` method

```js
var arr = [-1, 1, 0, -1, 4, 5, 2];

console.log(
  // iterate and comare values
  arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    // compare the values
    return (a === null || b < a) && b > -1 ? b : a;
    // set initial value as null to avoid selecting -ve value
    // in  case all values are negative   
  }, null)
)

// with ES6 arrow function

console.log(
  arr.reduce((a, b) => (a === null || b < a) && b > -1 ? b : a, null)
)
```

```js
var arr = [-1, 1, 3]; //should give 1
var arr1 = [-1, 2, -1]; //should give 2
var arr2 = [1, 0, -1, 4, 5, 2];

console.log(
  arr.reduce((a, b) => (a === null || b < a) && b > -1 ? b : a, null)
)
console.log(
  arr1.reduce((a, b) => (a === null || b < a) && b > -1 ? b : a, null)
)
console.log(
  arr2.reduce((a, b) => (a === null || b < a) && b > -1 ? b : a, null)
)
```

Comment: if -1 is at 0th index, it's returning -1.

Comment: @Droid : updated

Comment: @Droid : in case all are -ve values then what should be the output?

Comment: Thanx @Pranav C

Answer (score -2):

You're trying to remove negative numbers from your array?

```
const newArr = arr.filter(num => num >= 0)
```

Comment: not removing,just want minimum from array but if -1 ignore it. -1 can be in any position

Comment: `const minNotNegOne = arr.reduce((acc, val) => ((acc === null || val < acc) && val !== -1) ? val : acc, null)`